# Making a perfect hash (all consecutive buckets full), gperf or alternatives?

Tags: c, hashtable, gnu, lookup-tables

Let's say I want to build a perfect hash table for looking up an array where the predefined keys are 12 Months, thus I would want

```
hash("January")==0
hash("December")==11
```

I run my Month names through [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/"gperf"") and got a nice hash function, but it appears to give out 16 buckets(or rather the range is 16)!

```
#define MIN_HASH_VALUE 3
#define MAX_HASH_VALUE 18
/* maximum key range = 16, duplicates = 0 */
```

Looking at the generated gperf code, its hash function code does a simple return of len plus char value lookup from a 256 size table. Somehow, in my head I imagined a fancy looking function... :)

What if I want exactly 12 buckets(that is I do not want to skip over unused buckets)? For small sets as this, it really doesn't matter, but when I have 1000 predefined keys and want exactly 1000 buckets in a row?

Can one find a deterministic way to do this?

Comment: The goal of such hashes is to have a really fast hash function, thus the power of 2 (16 buckets for 12 months, 1024 buckets for your 1000 predefined keys). Why do you want to avoid such holes ? Do you agree to have a performance hit because of this requirement ?

Comment: Thanks! That explains it then.

Comment: To clarify, reason I asked was that I was looking to replace long "if then else if then else if" chains of strcmp with hashes. A few empty buckets would be a small price to pay, if the speedup is significant.

Comment: One slightly annoying problem with empty buckets is that it means, one has to hand pick buckets for each key(that is I am not sure whether April key points to bucket 3,4,5,6 or 7).

Comment: I really wonder what you need those perfect hashes for; my gut level suspicion is that you're solving a problem you don't really have, or that you have a performance problem and attacking the wrong cause. Of course I could be wrong and would be interested to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: Carl, you are absolutely right, I do not really have a perfomance problem at the moment. :) (rather, my bottlenecks are not at that particular spot)
This was more of a general curiosity question about gperf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only alternative to gperf I know is cmph : http://cmph.sourceforge.net/ but, as Jerome said in the comment, having 16 buckets provides you some speed benefit.

When I first looked at minimal perfect hasihing I found very interesting readings on [CiteseerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.91.6283) but I resisted the temptation to try coding one of those solutions myself. I know I would end up with an inferior solution respect to gperf or cmph or, even assuming the solution was comparable, I would have to spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: Accepted as answer for providing alternatives and additional information. As for coding a solution oneself, that is always a tempting path down to insanity..

Answer (score 6):

I was interested in the answer to this question & came to it via a search for `gperf`. I tried gperf, but it was very slow on a large input file and thus did not seem suitable. I tried  cmph but I wasn't happy with it. It requires building a file which is then loaded into the C program at run time. Further, the program is so fragile (crashes with "segmentation fault" on any kind of mistaken input) that I did not trust it. A further Google search led me to [this page](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html#pointer), and onward to [mph](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/devel/lang/c/!INDEX.short.html). I downloaded mph and found it is very nice. It has an optional program to generate a C file, called "emitc", and using it like

```
 mph < systemdictionaryfile | emitc > output.c
```

worked almost instantly (a few seconds with a dictionary of about 200,000 words) and created a working C file which compiles with no problems. My tests also indicate that it works. I haven't tested the performance of the hashing algorithm yet though.

Comment: I tried mph 1.2. When using `emitc -l`, the resulting hash function has a length parameter. That's nice, but the code seems to be broken. The for-loop still searched for a terminating `\0`. So the code generator is broken, I believe.
This is still a very neat tool! And I find it very sad that it seems to be unmaintained.

Answer (score 2):

There are many MPH solutions and algorithms, gperf doesn't yet do MPH's, but I'm working on it. Esp. for large sets. See https://gitlab.com/rurban/gperf/-/tree/hashfuncs

The classic **cmph** has a lot of constant overhead and is only recommended for huge key sets. Fixed version: https://github.com/rurban/cmph

There's the NetBSD **nbperf** and my improved variant: https://github.com/rurban/nbperf
which does CHM, CHM3 and BZD, with integer key support, optimizations for smaller key sets and alternate hash functions.

There's [Bob Jenkin's](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html) generator, and Taj Khattra's [mph-1.2](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/devel/lang/c/mph-1.2.tar.gz).

There are also two perl libraries to generate C lookups, one in PostgresQL (PerfectHash.pm) and one for late perl5 unicode lookups (regen/mph.pl), and a tool to compare various generators: https://github.com/rurban/Perfect-Hash